# How to loop through a list of Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, list, for-loop

I have about 13 dataframes. I need to write all this into csv. So I thought I got use a `for` loop. 
For example:

```
data1 = pd.Dataframe({'Name':['Tom', 'Jack', 'Steve', 'Ricky'],'Age':[28,34,29,42]})
data2 = pd.Dataframe({'Name':['ABC', 'EFG', 'HIJ', 'LMN'],'Age':[2,3,9,4]})
..
data13 = ....


list_df = [data1, data2,.....,data13]

for i in list_df:
    list_df[i].to_csv(...)
```

But it says a list can't have dataframes Error. What can I do to loop through the variable name of df?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in list_df:
i.to_csv(...)
```

here the variable i is the individual dataframe in the list, but i think you are thinking it to be index which is not the case.

```
for i,x in enumerate(list_df):
   list_df[i].to_csv(...)
```

this would work.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
for i in list_df:
    i.to_csv(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `i` references the dataframe. You can do one of the following ways:

```
for i in list_df:
    i.to_csv(...)
```

or:

```
for i,df in encounter(list_df):
  list_df[i].to_csv(...)
```